# Delphi access violation at address in module usp10.dll

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, runtime-error, access-violation

Ok here's the thing, my program runs perfect.. no errors at all until I add another button onto my form.

I have a stringgrid in parallel with an array[1..200].

I have a delete button:

```
Procedure TForm1.DeleteTeam(TeamName: string);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to TotalNumberOfTeams do
    begin
      if TeamName = SailingTeams[i].TeamName then
        begin
          sailingTeams[i].AvLapTime := 99999999;
          //puts one to delete with largest value to delete
          SortArray;
          //sorts it so it is at the end of array
          sailingTeams[TotalNumberOfTeams] := nil;
          TotalNumberOfTeams := TotalNumberOfTeams - 1;
          sortArray;
          UpdateGrid;
          Break;
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnDeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  TeamName : string;
  continue : integer;
begin
  TeamName := (strGrid.Cells[0,(strGrid.Row)]);
  continue := MessageDlg('Are you sure you wish to delete: '+teamName+'?',mtWarning, mbYESNO, 0);
  if continue = mrYES then
    DeleteTeam(TeamName);
end;
```

If I add a button and click it, then click delete I get the error :S :S

Just a home project for a 24 hour dingy race so efficiency of algorithms and stuff not important but any ideas as to why I'm getting this error?? :S

Comment: In which line does the exception come up?

Comment: Where is the stringlist?

Comment: @Lars when I debug and break no line is highlighted :S There shouldn't be anything wrong with the code either as it works when I don't have a button in - even if the button is a simple showmessage('hi!'); or something :S read something online about re-installing directX, should I? :L

Comment: @SertacAkyuz sorry stringGrid not List

Comment: Since you can nil 'sailingTeams[n]' it seems that you're keeping pointers to records in your array, or reference to objects. In that case you're actually not freeing the memory of the record and loosing the reference for it, or not freeing the object, IOW leaking memory. That's not related with your current problem though..

Comment: Hmmm still good to know, would I be better to do Free(sailingTeam[n]); . Sailing Team is an array of a class btw if that helps

Comment: @James - Sure. That would be before you nil the reference. But it should be more like 'sailingTeam[n].Free'.

Comment: We'd need to see more code to help I think

Comment: `FreeAndNil(sailingTeam[n]);`

Comment: I can't find the issue in your code above, mainly because I feel the relevant part of it isn't there - there's other procedures being called such as `sortArray` and `UpdateGrid`. However I would highly recommend not to use an array of a class, this is a road to issues and confusion. Instead, make use of the Object Pointers in the grid's rows as you add/delete them. It's best to keep data referenced in one place than trying to synchronize two different lists.

Comment: It's also a bad idea to keep a number somewhere else such as `TotalNumberOfTeams` which is supposed to represent the number of items in this list (I presume). Instead, if you use the array, `Length(MyArray);` or in the grid `MyGrid.RowCount;` or `MyGrid.RowCount - 1;` (`- 1` if you use a fixed row for coumn headers).